# Difference between RS PRO 846-171 and INA125P for strain gauge amplification?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I am implementing a solution to read several strain gauges at once.  Since I am using RS as my provider, I was about to buy the RS PRO 846-171 chip which is an amplifier specifically designed for strain gauges.

[RS PRO 846-171 datasheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1584/0900766b81584216.pdf)

[INA125P datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina125.pdf)

However, it's quite expensive, and I need like 5 of them, and after some more research I saw that most people use the INA125P chip, which is about 1/5 the price.  However, I cannot see what the difference between these two chips, they seem pretty equivalent.

Moreover, I am curious what does the INA125P even do that I can't do with a 20-cent op-amp?  Considering the INA125P is about 10€ and the RS chip is about 50€, I am a bit confused as to the difference in *magnitude* of cost when they all seem to do the same thing -- amplify a small voltage difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RS thing is some kind of module. You didn't supply a datasheet link and the one I found was a single page and inadequate.

Packaging can make a huge difference. The same part in a hermetic package might cost 10x as much. I'm not sure what the RS part offers over any other precision instrumentation amplifier, perhaps it's a legacy part from when in-amps were more rare and it's made from individual op-amps and resistors.

There are a variety of monolithic instrumentation amplifiers- parameters such as power supply range, noise, input offset voltage and offset voltage drift, CMRR, open-loop gain, bias current and other factors will help you match the available parts to your application. Frequency response (GBW product) is another but it probably won't have a strong effect on a strain gauge application.

There are a few hundred part numbers with < 200uV Vos. The cheapest one I see is the [AD8293](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8293G80_160.pdf) which costs less than $1.50 USD and has a fixed gain of 80 or 160. Limitations include a maximum supply voltage of +/-2.75V.

An instrumentation amplifier is a different part from an op-amp. It has two high-impedance inputs when configured with a fixed gain so it's ideal for measuring the output of a bridge type circuit. If you have only a half-bridge an op-amp of similar precision will usually be a better choice. You can make an instrumentation amplifier with 2 or 3 op-amps and some precision resistors, but usually (not always) the monolithic ones will be superior in CMRR and other behavior (such as input voltage ranges).

Comment: I looked at the 'datasheet' such as it is (and woefully inadequate as you note), and I would not buy it (even if I really needed something like that) on those grounds alone.

Comment: Hey thanks very much for all this info, very helpful!  Cheers, you answered my question. Yes, the datasheet on the website was not all that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting this as the link was misleading.  The biggest difference I see is that the RS PRO 846-171 is oven controlled.  ie. it takes 5 minutes to warm up.
This will provide great temperature stability over time, with the caveat that it takes a while to startup up the first time.

Comment: I don't think it's oven controlled. Especially not with a 4mA current draw. The warm-up time could just be to allow the thermal EMFs to settle out to meet their 200uV Vos spec.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Could be. I've only heard of oven controlled devices taking this long to start up, never for just a chip.  Plus the size is about right for it. Although as you state in your answer, the datasheet is pretty lacking so a lot of guessing going on with this part.

Comment: It's pretty common to specify non-monolithic modules and complete instruments such as meters with a warm-up time as long as 30 minutes or more. For example, [this](http://www.vishaypg.com/docs/50002/50002.pdf) Vishay one specifies 30 minutes. It just takes that long for temperature gradients to stabilize through a packaged instrument, so they can give a more optimistic specification number.